# Ansible | ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Below is Ansible script which will delete existing Zip file if exists, generate src html files using python commands and after html files generated, script will zip them:-

```
---
- name: run playbook locally
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: "CODE | PyDoc | Delete Zip"
      file:
        path: "{{ code_source_dev }}/doc/pydoc.zip"
        state: absent

    - name: CODE | Doc | Generating src html documents
      shell: "python -m pydoc -w src/*.py"
      ignore_errors: yes
      args:
          chdir: "{{ code_source_dev }}"
          executable: /bin/bash


    - name: CODE | Doc | Generating injectionModules html documents
      shell: "python -m pydoc -w injectionModules/*.py"
      ignore_errors: yes
      args:
          chdir: "{{ code_source_dev }}"
          executable: /bin/bash

    - name: CODE | Doc | Generating Test cases html documents
      shell: "python -m pydoc -w test/template_unit_test_framework.py"
      ignore_errors: yes
      args:
          chdir: "{{ code_source_dev }}"
          executable: /bin/bash

    - name: CODE | Doc | Zip html documents
      shell: "zip -r code-pydoc/pydoc.zip *.html"
      ignore_errors: yes
      args:
          chdir: "{{ code_source_dev }}"
          executable: /bin/bash
```

Ansible command :-

```
ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible-playbook -K acm/plays/emr/pydocs.yml
```

below error logs after executing from Jenkins:-

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/data/jenkins/workspace/cng-tesie-master-ci/acm/plays/emr/pydocs.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: run playbook locally
  ^ here
```

Ansible version used:-

```
+ ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.7.5
  config file = None
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ec2-user/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Sep 12 2018, 05:31:16) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
```

Comment: I don't see the offending line `- name: run playbook locally` in your question material.  Is that in a different playbook?

Comment: Its in line 2 of script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play specifications don't have a 'name' field.  So this is wrong:

```
- name: run playbook locally
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
```

It should look just like this:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
```

Comment: Thank you.. I have posted another question based on your suggestion . Please suggest.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54222894/ansible-execute-python-commands-via-ansbile